# Why string didn't write into file?

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

Function " writeToFile() " will be rapidly called to write string to text file .
but I didn't see any text in the file .

code:

```
 public class MyClass {
        private File data_file = new File("data_from_java.txt");
        public void writeToFile(String str){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(this.data_file, true);
            System.out.print(str);  // there is text shown in terminal 
            fos.write(str.getBytes());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();   // why file donesn't have text 
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `str`? (Generally speaking, you should write text using a `Writer`, e.g. an `OutputStreamWriter` wrapping the `FileOutputStream`. Calling `String.getBytes()` without specifying an encoding is a really bad idea.)

Comment: I expect you have more than one file called `data_from_java.txt` and you are updating one file while checking another, try reading the same file in your program to print out the last line.

Comment: file is fine, fos.isFile() return true , fos.writable() return True

Comment: tried by myself. the code does not appear to be wrong. it writes `str` to the file.

Comment: i just tried your code. it works just fine. make sure that you are checking the correct file. Use `data_file.getAbsolutePath();` for getting the correct file.

Comment: Your code works fine, it updates the file with str even if the file is opened, are you checking the correct file?

Comment: The code is working fine. check whether you are writing to the correct file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing raw bytes may cause problems with character encoding. As Jon Skeet said, use a writer...

```
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(data_file, true);
    writer.write(str);
} catch(IOException e) {
    // oh no!
} finally {
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this chunk of code:

```
final BufferedWriter fos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(data_file, true));
System.out.print(str);
fos.write(str);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

It worked for me although i did find my text file in a different place than i expected. Maybe a little searching would do already?

Answer (score 0):

IN ur code `fos.write(str.getBytes());` this line causes the problem it seems... write() method takes a byte as an argument.. u r giving array of bytes.. So change that line into

```
buf = str.getBytes();
for (int i=0; i < buf.length; i += 2) { 
f0.write(buf[i]);
}
```

Comment: this is not true. `write` method has an overloaded version that takes `byte[]` as input.